# Converting Hours to Minutes in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, time, string-formatting

I have a time span `2h 30min 22sec`.But I need the time bounded to UI in a format `150min 22sec`. How it is possible ? any built in function or formatting available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you require the total minutes, you could use a `MultiBinding`.

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}min {1}sec">
            <Binding Path="YourTimeSpan.TotalMinutes" Converter="{StaticResource ObjectToIntegerConverter}"/>
            <Binding Path="YourTimeSpan.Seconds"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

EDIT:

As pointed out in the comments, you will have to convert the `TotalMinutes` to an integer, to do this, you can use an `IValueConverter`.

```
public class ObjectToIntegerConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return System.Convert.ToInt32(value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to declare it in your `Resources`, for example:

```
<Window
    ...
    xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:Your.Converters.Namespace">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Converters:ObjectToIntegerConverter x:Key="ObjectToIntegerConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Note that `TotalMinutes` is a floating point value that includes seconds.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin Thanks for pointing that out, I've now catered for that in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar on XAML side but you can format your `TimeSpan` as;

```
var ts = new TimeSpan(2, 30, 22);

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}min {1}sec", 
                                (int)ts.TotalMinutes,
                                ts.Seconds));
```

generates

```
150min 22sec
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make your own:

```
public struct MyTimeSpan
{
  private readonly TimeSpan _data;

  public MyTimeSpan(TimeSpan data)
  {
    _data = data;
  }

  public override string ToString()
  {
    return string.Format("{0:f0}min {1}sec", _data.TotalMinutes, _data.Seconds);
  }
}
```